# Triangle Inequality of the Cartesian product with Max function

Tags: inequality, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.  Define $$d'((x,y),(z,w))=max\{d(x,z),d(y,w)\}.$$

I'm trying to prove the triangle inequality for this, but really don't have a clue how.  Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Max norm on $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: I don't think I can use a norm for this problem since this is from a section before norms are introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an outline of a proof.

First prove these two properties of the maximum of two real numbers (I use brackets for the max function where you use braces):

$$r \le s,\ t \le u\implies \max[r,t] \le \max[s,u]$$

$$\max[e+f,\ g+h] \le \max[e,g] + \max[f,h]$$

Each of those can be proved by cases. The second can also be seen from the fact that $\max$ is a norm on $\Bbb R^2$, as @user251257 hinted in a comment. With those facts in hand as well as the fact that $d$ is a metric on $X$, for

$$a=(a_x,a_y),\ b=(b_x,b_y),\ c=(c_x,c_y),\ \{a_x,a_y,b_x,b_y,c_x,c_y\}\subseteq X$$

we get

$$\begin{align}
d'(a,c) &= \max[d(a_x,c_x),\ d(a_y,c_y)] \\[1.5ex]
 &\le \max[d(a_x,b_x)+d(b_x,c_x),\ d(a_y,b_y)+d(b_y,c_y)] \\[1.5ex]
 &\le \max[d(a_x,b_x),\ d(a_y,b_y)]+\max[d(b_x,c_x),\ d(b_y,c_y)] \\[1.5ex]
 &= d'(a,b)+d'(b,c)
\end{align}$$